# Append multiple excel files into one file but different sheets in KNIME

Tags: knime

I have KNIME work flow which generates different worksheet, I want one single excel files with multiple sheets in KNIME workflow.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [Excel Sheet Appender (XLS)](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.ext.poi2.node.write2.XLSAppenderNodeFactory) node instead of the Excel Writer (XLS) node and it should work.

Comment: Excel sheet appender is now deprecated. [This](https://hub.knime.com/ipazin/spaces/Public/latest/2021_03_19_Consolidate_Multiple_Excel_Files_into_One~-ydjwcLiby44IfMT) will help.